# Custom views handler without table

Tags: 7, views

This seemed easy at first but I'm losing my hair on this.

I simply want to add a custom view handler that uses no table.

I tried to do as views php proposed, `$data['views']['mycustomfield']` in `hook_views_data`, but still

> mycustomfield colum not found.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually its easy. Just look at the implementation Views Global handlers which is available in [views.views.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!views.views.inc/7).

Below is the example how you can add field handler without having a table,

1. Specify your custom handlers in [hook_views_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) like below,

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_views_data().
    */
    function my_module_views_data() {
      $data['custom']['table']['group'] = t('Custom');
      $data['custom']['table']['join'] = array(
        // #global is a special flag which let's a table appear all the time.
        '#global' => array(),
      );

      $data['custom']['custom_handler'] = array(
        'title' => t('Custom Handler'),
        'help' => t('Custom Handler.'),
        'field' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_custom_handler',
        ),
      );

      return $data;
   }
   ```
2. Create a inc file for your handler an put your logic there. something like below
   Here the file name would be views_handler_custom_handler.inc

   ```
   /**
    * A handler to provide a field that is completely custom by the administrator.
    *
    * @ingroup views_field_handlers
    */
    class views_handler_custom_handler extends views_handler_field {
      function query() {
        // do nothing -- to override the parent query.
      }

      function option_definition() {
        $options = parent::option_definition();

        // Override the alter text option to always alter the text.
        $options['alter']['contains']['alter_text'] = array('default' => TRUE);
        return $options;
      }

      function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
        parent::options_form($form, $form_state);

        // Remove the checkbox
        unset($form['alter']['alter_text']);
        unset($form['alter']['text']['#dependency']);
        unset($form['alter']['text']['#process']);
      }

      function render($values) {
        // Render your content.
        return 'Sample';
      }
   }
   ```
3. Specify this new handler file in your module's info file
4. Clear the caches

Now the new field handler will be there in the field list.

Comment: Thx ! Exactly the 2 things I needed : override the query by specifying it empty, and join '#global'.

Comment: Is there a way to filter on these results? For instance, I've created a custom Field Handler for calculating a special "status" based on a user's relationship to an entity. I'd like to be able to filter via that status. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed!
But it seems that I cannot enable views relationships for a field handler like this. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166734/custom-views-field-handler-with-relationship-support-but-without-table Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To be complete: you would need to add hook_views_api too

```
function my_module_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module'),
  );
}
```

Comment: To be complete: You have to include handler in .info file 
files[] = views_handler_custom_handler.inc