# Custom views field handler with relationship support, but without table

Tags: views

I created a custom field handler following the very useful explanations here,
[Custom views handler without table](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80203/custom-views-handler-without-table)

The field handler picks the entity from each row and renders it in some way. (For simplicity lets just assume it renders a link to the entity using entity_label() and entity_uri(). It actually does more awesome stuff, but this is irrelevant here.)

Unfortunately, I found that I cannot configure a relationship when using this field handler. E.g. if I have a relationship "The node author", then I might want to render the title + link for the node author instead of the node.

Is there anything more I need to enable support for relationships?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function EXAMPLE_views_data() {
  $data = array();
  $data['EXAMPLE']['table']['group'] = t('Custom');
  // #global is a special flag which let's a table appear all the time.
  $data['EXAMPLE']['table']['join']['#global'] = array();

  $data['EXAMPLE']['custom_handler'] = array(
    'title' => t('EXAMPLE field handler'),
    'help' => t('EXAMPLE field handler'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => ExampleViewsFieldHandler::class,
    ),
  );

  return $data;
}
```

I could also post the code of the field handler class, but I supposed it is not really that relevant..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found one way to do this: Instead of registering just one handler, you register one handler per entity type. To save time, we can reuse the stuff already registered by [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity), with [entity_views_data()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!views!entity.views.inc/function/entity_views_data/7). This means, of course, the module needs to add Entity API as a dependency.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function EXAMPLE_views_data_alter(&$data) {

  foreach (entity_get_info() as $entity_type => $info) {
    if (!isset($data['views_entity_' . $entity_type]['rendered_entity'])) {
      // Only register for those entity types where Entity API already did its job.
      continue;
    }
    $data['views_entity_' . $entity_type]['EXAMPLE'] = array(
      'title' => t('Entity display plugin'),
      'help' => t('The @entity-type of the current relationship rendered using an entity display plugin.', array('@entity-type' => $info['label'])),
      'field' => array(
        'handler' => ExampleViewsFieldHandler::class,
        'type' => $entity_type,
        // The EntityFieldHandlerHelper treats the 'entity object' data
        // selector as special case for loading the base entity.
        // @todo Not sure if we really need this.
        'real field' => 'entity object',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And below is the field handler class, just a bit simplified.

Maybe it does a bit more than we really need here. E.g. we don't really need to create a render array for each row, we could work with html directly. But I think it is a good start.

```
class ExampleViewsFieldHandler extends \views_handler_field {

  function query() {
    // do nothing -- to override the parent query.
  }

  /**
   * Run before any fields are rendered.
   *
   * This gives the handlers some time to set up before any handler has
   * been rendered.
   *
   * @param object[] $rows
   *   An array of all objects returned from the query.
   */
  function pre_render(&$rows) {
    /**
     * @var string $entityType
     * @var object[] $entities
     */
    list($entityType, $entities) = $this->getResultEntities($rows);
    // Build the entities.
    $builds = $this->buildMultiple($entityType, $entities);
    foreach ($rows as $rowIndex => $row) {
      if (isset($builds[$rowIndex])) {
        /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */
        $row->example_field_builds[$this->position] = $builds[$rowIndex];
      }
      else {
        /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */
        unset($row->example_field_builds[$this->position]);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param object[] $rows
   *
   * @return mixed[]
   *
   * @see EntityFieldHandlerHelper::pre_render()
   */
  protected function getResultEntities(array $rows) {
    $relationship = !empty($this->relationship) ? $this->relationship : NULL;
    $field_alias = isset($this->real_field) ? $this->real_field : NULL;
    // Some views query classes want/allow a third parameter specifying the field name.
    /** @noinspection PhpMethodParametersCountMismatchInspection */
    list($entityType, $entities) = $this->view->query->get_result_entities($rows, $relationship, $field_alias);
    return array($entityType, $entities);
  }

  /**
   * @param object $row
   *
   * @return string
   */
  function render($row) {
    /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */
    return isset($row->example_field_builds[$this->position])
      ? drupal_render($row->example_field_builds[$this->position])
      : NULL;
  }

  /**
   * @param string $entityType
   * @param object[] $entities
   *
   * @return array[]
   *   A render array for each entity.
   */
  protected function buildMultiple($entityType, array $entities) {
    $builds = array();
    foreach ($entities as $rowIndex => $entity) {
      $builds[$rowIndex] = array(
        '#markup' => entity_label($entityType, $entity),
      );
    }
    return $builds;
  }
}
```